# loop mysql table and update contents from api grabs

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I would like to run a php script as a crontab every 10-15 minutes and updating a specific column in a mysql table. It pulls from a single API value and returns it and updates a cell. I feel that my current solution is O.K. ... but will get slower with a growing table... is there a better way?

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT address,api_getbalance FROM product_log");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $url = $row['api_getbalance']
        $address = $row['address']
        $newbalance = file_get_contents($url . '' . $address);
        $sql = "UPDATE product_log SET balance = ? WHERE address = ?";
        $Update = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);
        if($Update) {
             mysqli_stmt_bind_param($Update, 'ss', $newbalance, $address); 
             mysqli_stmt_execute($Update);
        } else {
             echo 'Data Not Updated';
             error_log(mysqli_stmt_error($sUpdate));
        }
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Your process is simple. Only improvement I would suggest would be to move the `prepare` to before you start looping on the results of the first select. You only need to prepare a statement once, then you can `execute` it with new parameters as many time as you like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prepare statement should be out of loop, it just initialize once and then parameters  bound within loop & executed. Updated code given below:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT address,api_getbalance FROM product_log");
$sql = "UPDATE product_log SET balance = ? WHERE address = ?";
$Update = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $url = $row['api_getbalance'];
    $address = $row['address'];
    $newbalance = file_get_contents($url . '' . $address);
    if ($Update) {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($Update, 'ss', $newbalance, $address);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($Update);
    } else {
        echo 'Data Not Updated';
        error_log(mysqli_stmt_error($sUpdate));
    }
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Awesome, well I guess since my queries were not massive it would be easier this way... I'll just add a `sleep(5)` to not exhaust the API calls on the same url

Comment: @NicholasRavanelli  If you SLEEP(5) you are limiting the volume to 12 updates a minute.  Is that OK?  Will there ever be more than 120 updates needed in 10 minutes? your planned CRON schedule.

Comment: Not at the moment, but I made the change to `sleep(2)` and run every 15 minutes just to give more time :)